# How can I instantly change the name of a new file I created?

Tags: bash

When I use the following command `solcjs --bin test.sol`, a file is created with the following name `byonotary_sol_BYONotary.bin`.

How can I instantly store this file name in a variable? I am hoping to run `solcjs --bin test.sol` and save its newly created file name into a variable in the same line of code.

Thanks.

Comment: use semicolon. All code cam be written in one line

Comment: There's no algorithm for the new filename, and it's not under your control at all? At first glance, I see no relation between `test.sol` and `byonotary_sol_BYONotary.bin` apart from `sol` appearing in the middle. Is `.bin` always at the end?

Comment: The relation is that within `test.sol` there is a smart contract called `byonotary` which is compiled into binary code using the command `solcjs --bin [file]`. Once it is compiled, solcjs renames the binary file based on the smart contract name within the file and not the file name itself. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Since the filename appears to be [generated based on the contracts in the file](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/blob/55a274b98a675719127e2b987e7d9ab4fcd71481/solcjs#L141), I would suggest creating a temporary directory for the output in order to make it easier to determine which "new" file is the one you're looking for:

```
d=$(mktemp -d -p .)
solcjs --bin --output-dir "$d" test.sol && set -- "$d"/*.bin && newfile=$1
```

This tells `mktemp` to create a directory relative to the current (`.`) directory. It then runs `solcjs` as before but with the `--output-dir` option. In the same line (or, more readably, on separate lines), it asks the shell to expand the `*.bin` wildcard in that new directory. Presumably the only matching file in there is the newly-created one. Adjust the `*.bin` if you stop using the `--bin` option, of course.

You could adjust the temporary directory name in various ways, such as using the current timestamp (e.g. `date +%s`) or using [`mktemp`'s template](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) feature.